# Aix: edquota problem

Tags: aix, quota, jfs

Simple but don't work
I did

```
edquota -u myuser
```

Open vi and I put those lines

```
/home: blocks in use: 16, limits (soft = 10, hard = 30) 
             inodes in use: 4, limits (soft = 0, hard = 0)
```

But give me

```
4050-311 /home:  blocks in use: 16, limits (soft = 10, hard = 30): formato errato
```

Why?
What is the correct format?
I try to put number in sequence: 16 10 30 4 0 0 
but after I did quotacheck nothing happens.

Comment: Did a line get deleted? "Quotas for user myuser:"?

Comment: The [format](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.security/setup_disk_quota_sys.htm "Setting up the disk quota system") appears to be correct (apart from the missing ```Quotas for user myuser:``` line Jeff mentioned) - are you sure there's no other [typo](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/fr.comp.os.unix/OC728ckMu1E/qMNscVsUT9sJ "Pb quotas - AIX.") involved when saving the file?

Comment: The line "Quotas for user..." is Deleted

Comment: Probably utf8?I will try today with LANG=C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution found,was a jfs2 filesystem so
the command to use is

```
j2edlimit
```

Edquota is for jfs only